# Как установить gecko в wine на ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wine, gecko

Ubuntu 18.04  x64
wine 3.0
.Net 4.0 4.5
winetricks
64-битный WINEPREFIX

Приложение под windows установлено в `/home/user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)`

Открывается с ошибками:

```
0106:err:mshtml:create_document_object Failed to init Gecko, returning CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE
```

Пробовал скачать версию wine_gecko-2.47-x86_64.msi  и положить в папку 'gecko' в директории  `/home/user/.wine/gecko` но при запуске оно не обнаружилось.

Comment: `apt install firefox-geckodriver` не пробовал?